# foundation & scroll pane 100% issue

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, jscrollpane

I have a section where it is to equal columns full width across. if you look a the 2nd column where it says content here if i do 100% on the jscroll-pane it shows horizontal bars, if i give it 98% it works properly but is not full width of the column. not sure why it adds horizontal bars to 100% but not 98%. I am not sure if foundation is causing my issue or not but if i take it out of the column and put in a row the 100% works fine just not in a large-6

> html

```
<section id="component">
    <div class="row expanded collapse">
      <div class="large-6 column">
      <img src="images/image.png">      
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 column">
        <div class="jscroll-pane">      
        Content Here

        </div>       
       </div>      
      </div>
</section>
```

> css

```
.jscroll-pane {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}


#component {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

> jscroll external css file

```
.jspContainer{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:100% !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}

.jspPane{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%!important;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    background: red;
}

.jspCap
{
    display: none;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspCap
{
    float: left;
}

.jspTrack
{
    background: #d8d8d8;
    position: relative;
}

.jspDrag
{
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack,
.jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.jspArrow
{
    background: #50506d;
    text-indent: -20000px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.jspArrow.jspDisabled
{
    cursor: default;
    background: #80808d;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
{
    height: 16px;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspArrow
{
    width: 16px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow:focus
{
    outline: none;
}

.jspCorner
{
    background: #eeeef4;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Yuk! CSS Hack for IE6 3 pixel bug :( */
* html .jspCorner
{
    margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Remove the display block and change overflow: auto to hidden; I believe this should help you.

```
.jscroll-pane {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```